# How to convert Excel to JSON and append it to existing JSON file?

Tags: python, json, excel, pandas

I have Excel file like this:

```
-------------------------
| myValue | myValue2 | myValue3 |
--------+-------+--------
|   1   |   A   |   AA|
|   2   |   B   |   BB|
|   4   |   C   |   CC  |
|   5   |   D   |   DD  |
|   6   |   E   |   EE|
|   7   |   F   |   FF  |
|   8   |   G   |   GG  |
--------------------------
```

I want to convert my Excel file to JSON like

```
{
"myValue":
{
"1":"1",
"2":"2"
},
"myValue2":
{
"A":"A",
"B":"B"
},
"myValue3":
{
"AA":"AA",
"BB":"BB"
}
}
```

I already have a JSON file like this, so I should append values from Excel to that file.
It should add values under "myValue" add to another JSON file under the "myValue" in that file. I already tried some solutions from site, but they did not work for me.
Also, the problem is that **myValue, myValue2, myValue3 are not always in the same order as displayed here**.
The ideal solution would be to find myValue in JSON file which already contains it and add values in it directly from Excel row which contains the same value.

Comment: Please add sample excel data

Comment: @abdulsaboor, added. :)

Comment: You may have some luck with if you're willing to load the Excel file using pandas: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html

Comment: There's also this if you don't need to transform the resulting dictionary: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html

Comment: @SimonCrowe, could you please add some sample code or example, as I am newbie in Python?

Comment: Sure, I can write something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This works**

```
# Importing dependencies 
import pandas
import json

# Reading xlsx into pandas dataframe
df = pandas.read_excel('../Data/18-12-21.xlsx')

# Encoding/decoding a Dataframe using 'columns' formatted JSON
jsonfile = df.to_json(orient='columns')

# Print out the result
print('Excel Sheet to JSON:\n', jsonfile)

# Make the string into a list to be able to input in to a JSON-file
json_dict = json.loads(jsonfile)

# write from and file to write to
with open('data.json', 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(json_dict, json_file)
```

**Output**

```
{
    "myValue": {
        "0": 1,
        "1": 2,
        "2": 4,
        "3": 5,
        "4": 6,
        "5": 7,
        "6": 8
    },
    "myValue2": {
        "0": "A",
        "1": "B",
        "2": "C",
        "3": "D",
        "4": "E",
        "5": "F",
        "6": "G"
    },
    "myValue3": {
        "0": "AA",
        "1": "BB",
        "2": "CC",
        "3": "DD",
        "4": "EE",
        "5": "FF",
        "6": "GG"
    }
}
```

Comment: will this work even if order of row values in excel is different? For example, one time is like shown, another time is myValue2, myValue3, myValue.

Comment: Yes it will, but this will of course change the JSON output you receive too.

Comment: okay, but will it affect on adding it to another JSON file? As it should find myValue in another file and add values below it from generated file?

Comment: is there a way change keys from "0", etc to same as values?

Comment: No it will not affect it, because I used the orient="columns" encoding appending other files will always identify the column headers first.

Comment: Yes, you can change the keys from "0", that is done when defining the index of your dataframe.

Comment: it works, but it does not append JSON to existing file, it overwrites existing values. Also, it does not convert some language specific characters. Is there a way to fix it, as this should be localization like script?

Just to clarify some things. I have one JSON file which is exactly the same as shown in question and I have to append to it new values.
For example:
I need to add
"1":"1" from excel to JSON under "myValue"

Comment: Just to mention that "myValue" in Excel is capitals and in existing JSON is lower case.

Comment: That wasn't the initial question, could you start another thread for this questions please and I and others in the community would be happy to help :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70407053/localization-from-excel-to-json-using-python