# Localization from Excel to JSON using Python

Tags: python, json, excel, pandas, localization

I have JSON file with different languages. I have to add more value that are read from Excel file.
For example, this is Excel table:

```
-------------------------------
| EN        | DE         | RU |
------------+------------+-----
| Ball      | Ball       | AA |
| Snow      | Schnee     | BB |
| Elephant  | Elephant   | CC |
| Woman     | Frau       | DD |
| Potato    | Kartoffeln | EE |
| Tomato    | F          | FF |
| Carrot    | G          | GG |
-------------------------------
```

JSON file in which I should add these values:

```json
{
    "en": {
        "Ball": "Ball",
        "Snow": "Snow"
    },
    "de": {
        "Ball": "Ball",
        "Snow": "Schnee"
    },
    "ru": {
        "Ball": "AA",
        "Snow": "BB"
    }
}
```

Note: en is EN in Excel. JSON keys must be exactly the same as values in English.
Tried this, but does not work:

```
# Importing dependencies 
import pandas
import json

# Reading xlsx into pandas dataframe
df = pandas.read_excel('Translations.xlsx')
df.iloc[0] = df.iloc[0].str.lower()
jsonfile = df.set_index('en', drop=False).to_json(indent=2)
# Encoding/decoding a Dataframe using 'columns' formatted JSON
jsonfile = df.to_json(orient='columns')

# Print out the result
print('Excel Sheet to JSON:\n', jsonfile)

# Make the string into a list to be able to input in to a JSON-file
json_dict = json.loads(jsonfile)

# write from and file to write to
with open('Localization.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as json_file:
    json.dump(json_dict, json_file)
```

Comment: So what is the question? Are you trying to convert the JSON to the table above?

Comment: No, I want to convert Excel to JSON and add it to an existing JSON file.
Imagine that I have to add all values below "Snow" from excel to JSON.

Comment: Imagine that I have to add all values below "Snow" from excel to JSON.
My colleague translates my texts and send me them in Excel like shown in question. My task is to create script which will add them to an existing JSON file.

Comment: So adding data to a JSON file?

Comment: I know how to read it, but struggling with encoding, as it does not encode some letters properly. Also, I am newbie, still learning Python. :)

Comment: Try opening the file with encoding `latin1`.

Comment: @richardec, is there a way to convert row values from excel to lower case?
For example: From EN to en.
I tried, but this code does not recognize encoding as argument
df = pandas.read_excel('Translations.xlsx')

Comment: Use `row.str.lower()` @crazyDev. e.g. `df.iloc[0] = df.iloc[0].str.lower()` to make all cells of the very first row all lowercase.

Comment: @AnalyticSolutions, yes

Comment: @AnalyticSolutions, just need to add values from excel file to appropriate places in JSON file..
Below
en in JSON file I need to add values that are in EN column in Excel file, etc.

Comment: @crazyDev please see my answer. It should do what you want now :)

Comment: @richardec, it does not work as expected. Could you see my code in question and correct it.
Once again expected input in excel table
Expected output is: added missing values to existing JSON file.

Comment: Can you upload `Translations.xlsx` somewhere so I can download it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert the dataframe to JSON, you can set `en` to be the index (and still *keep* the `en` column) and call `to_json`:

```
json = df.set_index('en', drop=False).to_json(indent=2)
```

Output:

```
>>> print(json)
{
  "en":{
    "Ball":"Ball",
    "Snow":"Snow",
    "Elephant":"Elephant",
    "Woman":"Woman",
    "Potato":"Potato",
    "Tomato":"Tomato",
    "Carrot":"Carrot"
  },
  "de":{
    "Ball":"Ball",
    "Snow":"Schnee",
    "Elephant":"Elephant",
    "Woman":"Frau",
    "Potato":"Kartoffeln",
    "Tomato":"F",
    "Carrot":"G"
  },
  "ru":{
    "Ball":"AA",
    "Snow":"BB",
    "Elephant":"CC",
    "Woman":"DD",
    "Potato":"EE",
    "Tomato":"FF",
    "Carrot":"GG"
  }
}
```

The whole script would probably be something like this:

```
import json

# Load old JSON from a file.
with open('old_json.json') as f:
    old_json = json.load(f)

# Load new data from spreadsheet.
new_data = pd.read_excel('...')

# Create dataframe from old JSON.
old_data = pd.DataFrame(old_json)

# Convert columns of both dataframes to lowercase.
new_data.columns = new_data.columns.astype(str).str.lower()
old_data.columns = old_data.columns.astype(str).str.lower()

# Append new data to old data and convert joined data to JSON.
new_json = pd.concat([old_data, new_data.set_index('en', drop=False)]).to_dict()

# Save new JSON to a file.
with open('new_json.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(new_json, f)
```

Comment: got error for en due to case sensitivity. Also issues with encoding. Some characters are ue4..

Comment: Check again @crazyDev. You may need `df.columns = df.columns.str.lowercase()` instead of `df.iloc[0] = ...`, like I've done in my answer.

Comment: site does not accept we transfer link. I need to support languages like japanese and then there is a struggle with encoding.

Comment: I can help a so much more if you can get me the file. Can you try a different link, like maybe Google Drive? Or GitHub?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n-WU9vGLHI3ua4B-XGGnSqwitNRh_xmi/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=118244896760079286038&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: The excel you sent has German, French, and Japanese, and a simple `pd.read_excel('Translations.xlsx')` worked without a single encoding problem.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm doing above. Change `'new_json.json'` in the above code to `'old_json.json'` and the file will be updated.

Comment: Are you having trouble still? :)

Comment: one more problem is that I need to use one excel column for two JSON values. For example, ja column should be used for ja and ja-jpn.

Comment: yes, cause in original excel with sensitive info, I have languages like chineese, poland, etc.
Also, is there a way, just to add values to existing json file without creating the new one?

Comment: Can you ask about the `ja-jpn` stuff in a _new_ question then, because this comments thread is already getting a bit lengthy...

Comment: If you do ask a new question, remember to mark this answer as accepted since it solved the immediate problem (I hope)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70407722/using-one-excel-column-on-two-places-json

Comment: Yes. Change this line `with open('new_json.json', 'w') as f:` to this `with open('old_json.json', 'w') as f:`

Comment: the problem is that I am not getting the original order which is problem. Is there a way to resolve it?