# Using one excel column on two places JSON

Tags: python, json, excel, pandas, localization

I have Excel file which I am converting to JSON and merge with existing JSON file.
The case is that In Excel I have column "ja" and values in it. IS there a way to add values from that column in JSON, on two places: "ja" and "ja-jpn"
Expected output:

```
"ja":{
    "Ball":"Ball",
    "Snow":"Schnee",
    "Elephant":"Elephant",
    "Woman":"Frau",
    "Potato":"Kartoffeln",
    "Tomato":"F",
    "Carrot":"G"
  },
  "ja-jpa":{
    Ball":"Ball",
    "Snow":"Schnee",
    "Elephant":"Elephant",
    "Woman":"Frau",
    "Potato":"Kartoffeln",
    "Tomato":"F",
    "Carrot":"G"
  }
```

Comment: For context, the previous question is https://stackoverflow.com/q/70407053/17242583

Comment: What would be your expected output?

Comment: I saw your edit. So basically you want to duplicate the `ja` column as `ja-jpn`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you convert your dataframe to JSON, just duplicate the column, like this:

```
if 'ja' in new_data.columns:
    new_data['ja-jpn'] = new_data['ja']
```