# Pandas concat automatically sort values

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have two data frames which I concatenate and then output them as JSON file.
The thing is that pandas automatically sort my values even if I set Sort=False.
Resetting index did not help. My index have to be set to 'en'.
Here is the line of code which makes me troubles:

```
new_json = pd.concat([old_data, new_data.set_index('en', drop=False)], sort=False).to_dict()
```

Input:

```
    "en":{
"skate":"skate",
"ball":"ball"
},
"de": {
"skate":"Schlittschuh laufen",
"ball":"Ball"
},
"ro":{
"ball":"baa",
"skate":"skateee"
}
}
```

Output I get:

```
  "en":{
"ball":"ball",
"skate":"skate"
},
"de": {
"ball":"Ball"
"ball":"Ball",
"skate":"Schlittschuh laufen"
},
"ro":{
"ball":"baa",
"skate":"skateee"
}
}
```

Is there a way to disable this kind of sorting?
The question is related to this: [Localization from Excel to JSON using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70407053/localization-from-excel-to-json-using-python) (The only change is that input in different languages is not always in the same order.)

Comment: Why does the order matter?

Comment: Can you provide sample data? So we can reproduce.

Comment: For script I am creating, order is very important. One of reasons is when I push changes to git.
For example, I change one line, pandas sort values and git sees it as more than one line changed.

Comment: @JAdel sample data are in question (input). 
If you need more code, I can update question.

Comment: @crazyDev I can't reproduce your issue, can you provide the input dfs and output df (before to_dict)?

Comment: is there any particular reason to use pandas? why not stick to vanilla python dicts instead?

Comment: I use pandas, because it is easier to manipulate with data from json and excel file.