# Prevent toDict sorting keys

Tags: python, json, pandas, sorting, dictionary

I am writing script which is adding values from an Excel file to an existing JSON file, but my output is changing its sorting, but I need to keep as it is.

```
  import json
import pandas as pd

# Load old JSON from a file.
with open('old_json.json') as f:
    old_json = json.load(f)

# Load new data from spreadsheet.
new_data = pd.read_excel('...')

# Create dataframe from old JSON.
old_data = pd.DataFrame(old_json)

# Append new data to old data and convert joined data to JSON.
new_json = pd.concat([old_data, new_data.set_index('en', drop=False)], sort=False).to_dict()

# Save new JSON to a file.
with open('new_json.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(new_json, f, sort_keys=False)
```

Seems that sort_keys=False and sort=False does not have any effect. It is very important to keep the original order of values, so that the new ones are at the end of the file.

Expected output is something like this:

```
{
  "en":{
    "Ball":"Ball",
    "Snow":"Snow",
    "Elephant":"Elephant",
    "Woman":"Woman",
    "Potato":"Potato",
    "Tomato":"Tomato",
    "Carrot":"Carrot"
  },
  "de":{
    "Ball":"Ball",
    "Snow":"Schnee",
    "Elephant":"Elephant",
    "Woman":"Frau",
    "Potato":"Kartoffeln",
    "Tomato":"F",
    "Carrot":"G"
  },
  "ru":{
    "Ball":"AA",
    "Snow":"BB",
    "Elephant":"CC",
    "Woman":"DD",
    "Potato":"EE",
    "Tomato":"FF",
    "Carrot":"GG"
  }
}
```

Current output is somehow sorted, not alphabetically, at least not fully.

```
  {
      "en":{
        "Ball":"Ball",
        "Snow":"Snow",
        "Potato":"Potato",
        "Tomato":"Tomato",
        "Carrot":"Carrot",
        "Elephant":"Elephant",
        "Woman":"Woman"    
      },
      "de":{
        "Ball":"Ball",
        "Snow":"Schnee",
         "Potato":"Kartoffeln",
        "Tomato":"F",
        "Carrot":"G",
        "Elephant":"Elephant",
        "Woman":"Frau"       
      },
      "ru":{
        "Ball":"AA",
        "Snow":"BB",
        "Potato":"EE",
        "Tomato":"FF",
        "Carrot":"GG",
        "Elephant":"CC",
        "Woman":"DD"        
      }
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide sample input data and the expected vs current output?

Comment: @taxevader added, this is also related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70407053/localization-from-excel-to-json-using-python

Comment: Will you please provide your current output as well?

Comment: Does `to_list( )` work? https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_list.html#pandas.Series.to_list

Comment: perhaps you rewrote your `old_json.json` at some point? you can also use the pandas `.read_json()` and `.to_json()` methods instead of bothering with Python's `json` lib

Comment: @ti7 Hmm, I don't think so, I changed code a bit, so now, new_json.json is replaced with old_json.json, because I actually have to update old_json.json without soring.

Comment: @Icyvapor, I tried, but does not work to me, it is giving me an error when I change toDict to toList()

Comment: Why do the keys need to be in a particular order?

Comment: The dictionary data type when converted to json string isn't supposed to follow a specific order. I think you should consider converting the data to csv to keep the order consistent

Comment: @Nick this is project specific script which must follow the original order and use format it as JSON file

Answer (score 1):

If key order is critical in the output, you could make use of an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to reorder the keys from your existing output to what you desire. For example (assuming `old` contains your current output):

```py
from collections import OrderedDict

wordorder = ['Ball','Snow','Elephant','Woman','Potato','Tomato','Carrot']
langorder = ['en','de','ru']

new = { lang : { word : old[lang][word] for word in wordorder } for lang in langorder }
new_json = json.dumps(new, indent=2)
print(new_json)
```

Output:

```
{
  "en": {
    "Ball": "Ball",
    "Snow": "Snow",
    "Elephant": "Elephant",
    "Woman": "Woman",
    "Potato": "Potato",
    "Tomato": "Tomato",
    "Carrot": "Carrot"
  },
  "de": {
    "Ball": "Ball",
    "Snow": "Schnee",
    "Elephant": "Elephant",
    "Woman": "Frau",
    "Potato": "Kartoffeln",
    "Tomato": "F",
    "Carrot": "G"
  },
  "ru": {
    "Ball": "AA",
    "Snow": "BB",
    "Elephant": "CC",
    "Woman": "DD",
    "Potato": "EE",
    "Tomato": "FF",
    "Carrot": "GG"
  }
}
```

Note I've used constant lists for `wordorder` and `langorder`, you could extract them from your original file using something like:

```py
langorder = old_json.keys()
wordorder = old_json[langorder[0]].keys()
```

Comment: does this make sense? I ask you becuase, I still get sorted result

Comment: @crazyDev are you doing this after you output from pandas?

Comment: @crazyDev is it possible to put sample data (from `old_json.json` and the excel file) that demonstrates the issue into the question? that way I can test my code in the exact environment you have

Comment: actually "en" does not make problem, but other languages are not keeping desired order.

Comment: Without actual sample data as described in my previous comments I can't really debug this any more; it works with `old` set to what is the current output in your question